# Can't retrive the good information from JSON on C#

Tags: c#, youtube-api, json.net

I'm trying to get information from the Google API (YT). I need to take the videoId from the API of Google.

So I download the JSON page and trying to deserialize my result but he doesn't works.

This is the JSON result

```
    {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/E6IhaTG5XEbqo_uSYhCcIvQhtwY\"",
   "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
   "pageInfo": {
   "totalResults": 180,
   "resultsPerPage": 50
   },
  "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/0cAZGJiF62yaNO7GwJlJBsc7DqY\"",
   "id": "UExNQzlLTmtJbmNLdFB6Z1ktNXJtaHZqN2ZheDhmZHhvai41RDlFNzlCQjE5NzcyQTYx",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-05-19T13:47:40.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCs72iRpTEuwV3y6pdWYLgiw",
    "title": "Katy Perry - Dark Horse (Official) ft. Juicy J",
    "description": "Bla bla bla",
    },
    "channelTitle": "#RedMusic: Just Hits",
    "playlistId": "PLMC9KNkIncKtPzgY-5rmhvj7fax8fdxoj",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "0KSOMA3QBU0"
    }
   }
  },
```

And this is my code for taking the videoId

```
JObject jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x.Result);
foreach (var item in jObj["items"])
{
  string title = item["videoId"].ToString();
}
```

And when I'm start my app I have an error with System.NullReferenceException.

Where is my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Please check your JSON sample - I suspect you did not copy and paste it correctly due to the weird comma after bla"

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`string title = item["videoId"].ToString();`

to:

`string title = item["resourceId"]["videoId"].ToString();`

Comment: I have tried, got the same problem but thanks for your answer

Comment: If you have this code, which of the three lines get the error ? `var g = item["resourceId"]; var h = g["videoId"]; string title = h.ToString();`

Comment: string title = h.ToString(); got the error look at this [link](http://i.imgur.com/ArK4ODY.png)

Comment: That screenshot is not showing my code (resourceId is not mentioned for example). It is showing your original code. Can you try the code I suggested?

Comment: Yep sorry ^^ Now it's good but same problem [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/ULhDSuF.png)

Comment: That code is not the code I suggested. Can you use the code I suggested and show a screenshot of the exception then?

Answer (score 0):

```
JObject jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in jObj["items"])
{
    string title = item["resourceId"]["videoId"].ToString();
}
```

You are missing ["resourceId"].

Comment: I have tried, got the same problem but thanks for your answer

Comment: In your screenshot still you are missing `["resourceId"]`.

Comment: It should be `var h = g["videoId"];`. Not `var h = item["videoId"]`. And then convert to string.

Comment: Corrected but problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've found the solution, i've added in var g the next item

```
var g = item["snippet"]["resourceId"];
```

If I don't put the good "path" it doesn't works.
So now it's working and I have the video link.

Thanks all for your help !

Comment: If that works, the sample JSON you showed in your question is incorrect. resourceId is not a child of snippet in your original question.